# Updating a table in a Mysql database

Tags: mysql, database

Let's say I have  in a table named threadloc:

```
id  thread
4   1
3   2
2   3
1   4
```

for a table

I want to change the table value of thread so that I can pick any thread and put in on the bottom (id 1) and push all the other threads up one.

So like I pick 2 it would be:

```
id  thread
4   1
3   3
2   4
1   2
```

Comment: Need more details on logic behind this. anythread above 2 should be incremented by 1 right?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE threadloc SET ID = ID + 1 WHERE thread <> @currentThread AND ID < @currentID;
UPDATE threadloc SET ID = 1 WHERE thread = @currentThread
```

edit: now it doesn't change higher IDs

Comment: This will change the thread 1 too which is not expected in given output.

Comment: hm yeah, you dont get a ids from 1 to 4, but if you just want to have the right order it should be ok. otherwise you have to add a second where clause and prevent the higher ids from changing